# Unable to amend membership if it previously was related to an organisation record

Tags: civimember

I'm having an issue where by a drupal user has renewed their membership using a different membership type. The original membership was held on an organisation contact record and related to the individual contact record associated with the drupal user, but when it is renewed as a membership that no longer requires a relationship, I cannot amend the membership from the individual record OR the organisation record. In fact, on the organisation record, the membership remains 'expired' in status.

If I try to 'view' the membership, I cannot see anything on the pop up screen.

Has any one experienced this and knows how to amend it?

Comment: sounds odd. when you get to 'view' can you right click, open in a new tab, and see if you get an error msg. also if you have access to the db perhaps go check the values in the row in the membership table and see if anything stands out as wrong. am assuming this is a separate Membership ID, not the same ID as the one 'owned' by the Org.

Comment: Thanks! If I open 'view' in another tab I get 'DB Error: syntax error' - I'm wondering if that's actually an issue aside from this one (we've had a lot of issues with smarty templates.) Unfortunately I don't have access to the tables but will ask our devs if they can have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to delete the membership on the Ogranisation record: 
I made a copy of the membership and contribution on the owner record (so we've still got the historical data), then deleted the faulty membership from the owner record and this removed it from the individual contact record. Bit messy but did the trick.